# How would I keep the image in place when making browser width smaller?

Tags: html, css, debugging, media-queries

I have a media query that aligns a button directly next to another upon making the width of the browser smaller at a width of 991.  However, as I make the browser width less than 991px, the button begins to slide underneath the other button as opposed to staying in place.

During my attempt to fix it, I tried making its position absolute but that didn't work.  I've also tried a laundry list of other things but had no luck

How would I make it stay in place as I make my browser width less than 991px?

My apologies in advance if it seems like a vague question.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
 a.myImg {
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 11em;
      margin-top: -7.7em;
  }
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="#" class="myImg col-md-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
            <img src="picture/path"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show what containers they are in? Like divs or tables.?

Comment: @KatyH. Posted,  I posted one of them because the other button is the exact same.

Comment: try to add `max-width: none;`

Answer (score 0):

@greyskies I'm not entirely sure I understand exactly what you'd like to achieve but I created two examples for you on [codePen](https://codepen.io/juditp/pen/jdQLzo)

Scenario 1:
You have both of your buttons in the same 'box' -> in this case I added some css to support floating left of your buttons and make them half size of the width of viewport

Scenario 2:
You have your buttons in two boxes next to each other -> for this I just modified the classes on the boxes from 'col-md-6' to 'col-6'

If this is not what you are after, it would be help if you could attach a screenshot of the desired result

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid v1">
  <h1>version 1</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a href="#" class="myImg">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=button-1"/>
        </a>
      <a href="#" class="myImg">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=button-2"/>
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid v2">
  <h1>version 2</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <a href="#" class="myImg">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=button-1"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <a href="#" class="myImg">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=button-2"/>
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

COMPILED CSS:

```
.myImg img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.v1 .myImg {
  width: 48%;
  margin: 0 1%;
  float: left;
}
```